# I got error message "operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" when I try to generated specflow Step Definition Report

Tags: specflow

I got above error message when I try to use specflow.exe to generate specflow Step Definition Report, the command I used is:

```
specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport ..\\..\\..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
```

Any ideas and suggestions, Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue when I was using StepDefinition instead of Given-When-Then in my step definitions. By switching back to Given-When-Then it started working.

Instead of using the `[StepDefinition(@"...")]` use a `[Given(@"...")]` for example:

```
    [Given("I take a screenshot")]
    [When("I take a screenshot")]
    [Then("I take a screenshot")]
    public void takeScreenshot()
    {
        screenShots.Add(((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot());
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean the attribute above the step definition method was annotated as `[StepDefinition(@"...")]` instead of `[Given(@"...")]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Any with a StepDefinition attribute caused mine to break. I edited all of mine to be Given, When and Then individually.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your answer. Would you mind editing your post with some example code of what you mean?